# What are the differences/(dis)advantages of zenity vs notify-send?

Tags: desktop-environment, notifications, zenity, notify-send, libnotify

There is both [zenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) and [notify-send](https://ss64.com/bash/notify-send.html). (on Fedora/GNOME at least, both seems to be pre-installed.)

So considering I want to show notifications, what are the differences between these too ones?

Is there anyone that is installed in more distros or so (by default)? Is the process of showing notifications any different? Is anyone maybe more compatible to some desktop environments? Is it even available on some desktop environments?

I also noticed the documentation on `notify-send` is pretty spare. In my Fedora installation, it does not even have a man page…

Comment: At least in [Fedora Silverblue](https://silverblue.fedoraproject.org/), [I noticed](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/why-is-notify-send-included-in-silverblue-but-not-zenity/2038?u=rugk) there is `notify-send` by default, but no `zenity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Functionality comparison

`zenity --notification` is equivalent to `notify-send` for the most simple cases.

For example, these two commands are equivalent:

```
$ zenity --notification --text=Title
$ notify-send Title
```

and so are these:

```
$ notify-send Title 'Long text message'
$ zenity --notification --text='Title\nLong text message'
```

As you can see, the syntax for `notify-send` is shorter and simpler, because it is a specialised tool, while `--notification` is just one of the many commands available in `zenity`.

Differences are:

- `notify-send` has an `expire-time` option, which however, according to the current man page, is ignored by both Ubuntu's Osd and the Gnome shell.
- `zenity` has a `--listen` option which can change the appearance of the notification without closing and reopening it: message displayed, visibility and icon can all be changed by sending appropriate strings to zenity's standard input.
- setting an icon requires just `--icon` for `notify-send` while it requires `--listen` and `icon: error` command on standard input for zenity.
- category and urgency are set with dedicated options in `zenity`, while they require a `--hint` option.

Note that you need to explicitly kill the `zenity` process when using `--listen`, because it keeps listening on standard input even after it is closed (this is a bug, I suppose). This is not a problem for complex procedures where the notification changes dynamically, but it makes things unnecessarily complex for simple cases.

Also note that the `--hint` option of `zenity` is briefly mentioned by `zenity --help-notification`, but it is not mentioned in the man page.

Both category and urgency are documented in the [Desktop Notifications Specification](https://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x344.html).

### Alternatives

`dialog` and the old `whiptail` are possible alternatives, but I don't see any advantage in using them for notifications unless you cannot install `notify-send` or `zenity` or you are already using them for other purposes, since both have much more functionality than just notifications.